# No info passing to the modal window from product listing: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _vm.selectProduct is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-modal

I have a product listing that has a more details button which will open a modal window that contains that particular product's information. I used $emit for passing the information from my product's page to the modal window. I see the modal window open but I don't see that particular product's information that is defined in `Modal_window.vue`.

I keep getting the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _vm.selectProduct is not a function"

vue.esm.js?efeb:1897 TypeError: _vm.selectProduct is not a function
```

This is my code:

**Product_listing.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <div v-for="product in productsWithHeadlines" :key="product.id">
      <div class="one">
        <span>{{product.name}}</span>
      </div>
      ...
      <div class="seven">
        <b-btn class="more_details_button" @click="selectProduct(product)">More details</b-btn>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  component: {
    modal_window: Modal_window
  },

  data() {
    return {
      showModal: false,
      selectedProduct: undefined,

      products: [
        {
          ID: "1",
          Name: "Product_1",
          Headline_1: "Headline 1",
          top_feature_1:
            "This is the description of the feature of product 1 under the first headline",
          Headline_2: "Headline 2",
          top_feature_2:
            "This is the description of the feature of product 1 under the second headline",
          Headline_3: "Headline 3",
          top_feature_3:
            "This is the description of the feature of product 1 under the third headline",
        },
{
          ID: "2",
          Name: "Product_2",
          Headline_1: "Headline 1",
          top_feature_1:
            "This is the description of the feature of product 2 under the first headline",
          Headline_2: "Headline 2",
          top_feature_2:
            "This is the description of the feature of product 2 under the second headline",
          Headline_3: "Headline 3",
          top_feature_3:
            "This is the description of the feature of product 2 under the third headline",
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    selectProduct(product) {
      this.selectedProduct = product;
      this.$emit("openModalWindow", this.selectedProduct);
    },

    productsWithHeadlines() {
      return this.products.map(product => {
        const totalKeys = Object.keys(product).length;
        const headlines = [];
        for (let index = 1; index < totalKeys; index += 1) {
          const text = product[`Headline_${index}`];
          const feature = product[`top_feature_${index}`];
          if (text && feature) headlines.push({ text, feature });
        }

        return {
          id: product.id,
          name: product.Name,
          headlines,
        };
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Modal_window.vue**
I am using the headlines data element in the modal window along with the name.

```
<template id="modal-template">
  <b-modal id="showModal" :hide-footer="true" ok-title="Buy Now" size="lg" :title="product.name">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="inner-nested">
        <div class="inner-one">
          {{ product.name }}
       </div>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="(headline, index) in product.headlines" :key="index">
              <div>{{ headline.text }}</div>
              <div>{{ headline.feature }}</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showModal: false,
      product: { type: Object, default: null }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    openModal(newProduct) {
      console.log(newProduct);
      this.product = newProduct;
      this.$bvModal.show("showModal");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I would appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: You haven't added the component inside product-listing.vue, also move selectProduct from computed to methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error stated - selectProduct is not a function which itself clears the problem here.

Understand how computed and methods property of `vue` differs.

**Computed**
These properties are converted as the vue property with getters and setters which means you can either get a value from it or either set a predefined value, It doesn't accepts a parameter to it

Ex -

```
computed : {
  hello() {
    return 'helloWorld' // Getting a value 
  }
}
```

you will use it as `this.hello` where as methods which are perfectly a replica of a normal `function` in JS where with the capabilities of understanding other vue property

```
methods : {
      hello(name) {
        return 'hello' + name // Getting a value 
      }
    }
```

As said it's a `fn` so it can have parameter also and you can use it as a `fn` like `this.hello(name)`

In your case you probably wish to move your `selectProduct` property to `methods` property instead as `computed` property.